# Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be intervals in $\Bbb R$, and find an injective and surjective function from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

So here is this question I got stuck on:

Let $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ be intervals (not sure if that's the correct term) on $\Bbb R$, so that $a<b$, $c<d$. Find an injective and surjective function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow(c,d)$.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I get these question a lot. Is that some way of thinking, or some general method I should follow to make these question easier for me to solve?

Comment: Interval is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

**Edit:** It's not supposed to be a square.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your constant help!

Comment: Congratulations for the 5k! And wow, I have exactly the same score right now.

Comment: @ohad No problem.

Comment: @azimut Thank you and congrats :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Try a function of the form $x \mapsto sx + t$ with $s,t\in\mathbb R$.