# Function to map a range of $[-1,1]$ to a range of $[0,1]$

Tags: functions

I'm not capable of 'rigorously' defining the problem I have but this is the best I can do.

If I have a set of points that range from $-1$ to $1$ inclusive and I have to transform the data so that it fits onto a range of $0$ to $1$. What's the simple function to do this?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367296/let-a-b-and-c-d-be-intervals-on-r-and-find-an-injective-and-surjective-func) might help.

Comment: You want some transformation $\phi$ such that $\phi(-1)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi$ is linear. So we might think something like $\phi(x)=ax+b$, and you have to find $a,b$ such that $\phi(-1)=...$ etc. So, basically, we have to solve system of two equation.

Answer (score 3):

$$
x \mapsto \frac{x+1}{2}
$$
${{{{{{{}}}}}}}$

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I just couldn't come up with it