# prove that 2 closed interval sets have equal cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(see improved and answered version of this question at: [showing $f$ to be a bijection but stuck trying to show that $f$ is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452226/showing-f-to-be-a-bijection-but-stuck-trying-to-show-that-f-is-surjective))

recall that the closed interval $[a,b]$={${x \in \mathbb{R} \vert a\le x \le b}$}

prove that $\vert [2,5] \vert$=$\vert [-2,3] \vert$

can someone please help me prove this? I know proving these involves finding an injection, surjection or bijection but without being given an actual function im pretty clueless.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider the line  through the points $(2,-2)$ and $(5,3)$.

Comment: Hint: It's a high school algebra 1 problem (meaning you don't have to look for anything mathematically advanced) to find a function of the form $mx + b$ (with $m \neq 0)$ that takes $2$ to $-2$ and $5$ to $3.$ (And after posting this, I see David Mitra beat me to it . . .)

Comment: Very close to being a duplicate of [Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be intervals in $\Bbb R$, and find an injective and surjective function from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367296).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f\colon[2,5]\longrightarrow[-2,3]$ by $f(x)=-2+\frac53(x-2)$. It is a bijection and therefore $[2,5]$ and $[-2,3]$ have the same cardinal.

Comment: so what steps did you take to get $f(x)$ ? also im writing a proof for this question so as part of the proof should i prove that $f(x)$ is a bijection?

Comment: @kr1s The first interval has length $3$, and the second one has length $5$; that's where that $\frac53$ factor comes from. Since I wanted a map of the type $f(x)=\alpha+\frac53(x-2)$ such that $f(2)=-2$, I took $\alpha=-2$.

Comment: oh i see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \lt b,$ real.

$f: [a,b]$ $ \rightarrow$  $[0,1]$ ,

$x \mapsto f(x):= \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ is a bijection .

Hence $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$ have the same cardinality.

Can you take it from here?